# Screen recorder producing huge AVI files

Tags: c#, compression, video

I'm currently trying to make a screen recorder in C#, and so far it works but the problem is that something as simple as a 20second video will take about 1GB of space. I have it setup so a timer continuously takes screenshots with this method:

```
void takeScreenshot()
{
    Rectangle bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            //Add screen to bitmap:
            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
        //Create and save screenshot:
        string name = path + "//screenshot-" + fileCount + ".jpeg";
        bitmap.Save(name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        inputImageSequence.Add(name);
        fileCount++;

        //Dispose of bitmap:
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And then it stores those pictures in a temporary folder in the `D://` drive, and then when it's done it takes all the pictures and creates an AVI video out of them like this:

```
//Set bounds of video to screen size:
Rectangle bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
int width = bounds.Width;
int height = bounds.Height;

var framRate = 5;

using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
{
    //Create new video file:
    vFWriter.Open(outputPath+"//video.avi", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

    //Make each screenshot into a video frame:
    foreach (var imageLocation in inputImageSequence)
    {
        Bitmap imageFrame = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation) as Bitmap;
        vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(imageFrame);
        imageFrame.Dispose();
    }
    vFWriter.Close();
}
//Delete the screenshots and temporary folder:
DeletePath(path);
```

Any help on reducing the inefficiency of this is appreciated, I'm fairly new to this kind of programming.

Answer (score 13):

**takeScreenshot()**

- Based on the [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing `takeScreenshot()` => `TakeScreenshot()`
- You are enclosing the usage of the `Bitmap` inside a `using` statement which is the way to go but calling `Dispose()` on that `Bitmap` is superfluous because that is what a `using` statement is doing.
- If you have two `using` statements without any code between you can stack them which saves one level of indentation like so (already removed the `Dispose()`)

  ```
  using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
  {
      //Add screen to bitmap:
      g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);

      //Create and save screenshot:
      string name = path + "//screenshot-" + fileCount + ".jpeg";
      bitmap.Save(name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      inputImageSequence.Add(name);
      fileCount++;
  }
  ```
- Comments should explain **why** something is done in the way it is done. Let the code itself tell **what** is done by using meaningful named things. In this way your comments won't lie like e.g `//Create and save screenshot:` which isn't what that code does. Saving yes but no creating of a screenshot is taking place.

---

**Creating the video**

- Try to be consistent. Here you create a `Bitmap` and call `Dispose()` instead of using a `using` statement. In addition, sometime you use `var` and sometimes you use the concrete type although the type is seen at first glance.
- If you are using the `as` operator you should always add a `null` check for that object because an `as` operator won't throw an exception but the resulting object may be `null` which will trigger an exception somewhere else.

Implementing these points will look like this:

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
var width = bounds.Width;
var height = bounds.Height;

var framRate = 5;

using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
{
    vFWriter.Open(outputPath+"//video.avi", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

    foreach (var imageLocation in inputImageSequence)
    {
        using(var imageFrame = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation))
        {
            vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(imageFrame);
        }
    }
    vFWriter.Close();
}
DeletePath(path);
```

---

My guess about the big file size is that you are using the `VideoCodec.Raw`. Try to change it to some other codec and see if this helps.

Answer (score 8):

You could write the screenshots directly to the video stream. This could save you a lot of disk space depending on your capture time.

To make the video file smaller you need to use a codec that compresses the output like MPEG-4.

Finally you could encapsulate the recording in its own class:

```
public sealed class ScreenRecorder : IDisposable
{
    private readonly VideoFileWriter videoFileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
    private readonly string videoFilePath;
    private readonly Rectangle bounds;

    public ScreenRecorder(string videoFilePath, Rectangle bounds, int frameRate = 5, VideoCodec videoCodec = VideoCodec.MPEG4)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(videoFilePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Must be a valid filename", nameof(videoFilePath));
        }

        if(frameRate < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(frameRate));
        }

        this.videoFilePath = videoFilePath;
        this.bounds = bounds;
        videoFileWriter.Open(videoFilePath, bounds.Width, bounds.Height, frameRate, videoCodec);
    }

    public void TakeScreenshot()
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(ScreenRecorder));
        }

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                //Add screen to bitmap:
                g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }

            videoFileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bitmap);
        }
    }

    public void Stop() => Dispose();

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposed = false; // To detect redundant calls

    void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                videoFileWriter.Dispose();
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using string concatenation for creating file paths opens you up to a whole lot of headache. Should you use `/`, `//`, `\` or `\\`? The answer depends on the environment you are running in. Luckily, the `Path` class can do all this logic for us:

Instead of

```
path + "//screenshot-" + fileCount + ".jpeg";
```

you could do

```
Path.Combine(path, $"screenshot-{fileCount}.jpeg");
```

and instead of

```
outputPath+"//video.avi"
Path.Combine(outputPath, "video.avi")
```

This way you don't have to worry about using the right fileseparator.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all your help as well as the help of many others, I have actually fully compelted the screen recorder and have typed up an explanation here if anyone is interested: https://benbcompsci.wordpress.com/2018/12/04/c-screen-recorder/